# Transforming expression containing powers of parameter

Tags: simplifying-expressions, expression-manipulation

I want to construct a `Transform` function which works like this:

```
Transform[2^(-2 + s)*A^(-s + v)*x^(-n - s + v), s] = 1/4*A^v*x^(-n + v)*(2/(A*x))^s
```

Parameter `s` is very important.

Written more clearly : $$2^{-2+s} A^{-s+v} x^{-n-s+v} \to \frac{1}{4} A^v x^{-n+v} \left(\frac{2}{A x}\right)^s$$

or:

$$2^{-2+s} A^{-s+v} x^{-n-s+v}\to \frac{A^v x^{-n+v} \left(\frac{2}{A x}\right)^s}{2^2}$$

I tried:

```
 FullSimplify[2^(-2 + s)  A^(-s + v)  x^(-n - s + v), 
 Assumptions -> {s ∈ Reals, A > 0, x > 0, 
 n ∈ Integers, v ∈ Reals}]
 (*2^(-2 + s) x^-n (A x)^(-s + v)*)
```

But it does not produce the result I want.

I have tried many times and spent a lot of time on it, but I can't do it.

Comment: The problem is that Mathematica will auto-convert `1/4*2^s` to `2^(-2 + s)`. So your will be fighting it all the time. For you original expression, if you add `Assumptions -> A > 0` for the Simplify command it will get you closer to what you want.

Comment: I think using Pattern matching with Replacement is your best bet on this. Not Simplify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've not given us a lot of test cases, so here is an implementation with [`FactorList`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FactorList.html) that works for your example.

```
deferPower[expr_, pow_] := Defer[expr^pow];
transform[expr_, s_] := Module[{factors, paramFactors},
  factors = FactorList[expr];
  paramFactors = Cases[factors, {x_^ss_ /; ! FreeQ[ss, s], b_}];
  (Times @@ Power @@@ Complement[factors, paramFactors]) *
   deferPower[Times @@ Power @@@ (paramFactors /. {x_^ss_ /; ! FreeQ[ss, s], b_} :> 
    {x^(ss/s), b}), s]
]

transform[2^(-2 + s) A^(-s + v) x^(-n - s + v), s]
(* 1/4 A^v x^(-n + v) (2/(A x))^s *)

transform[t^(-((1 + n - 2 s)/(2 n))), s]
(* t^(-(1/2) - 1/(2 n)) (t^(1/n))^s *)
```

Comment: Excellent, Good Job 1+. Thanks.

Comment: I found the case your code dosen't work ? `transform[t^(-((1 + n - 2 s)/(2 n))), s]` it should to be: `t^(-(1/2) - 1/(2 n)) (t^(1/n))^s` or in latex: $$t^{-\frac{1+n-2 s}{2 n}}\to t^{-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2 n}}
   \left(t^{1/n}\right)^s$$ ?

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk, I have fixed the code to account for such cases.

Comment: Thank you. Excellent.