A hypergeometric series function
Maple and Mathematica are very efficient to find closed form of a hypergeometric function as for example:
$$\sum _{k=0}^{\infty } \frac{(-4)^k z^k \Gamma \left(1 k+\frac{1}{6}\right) \Gamma \left(\frac{k}{2}+\frac{1}{6}\right)}{k! \Gamma (3 k+1)}=\frac{1}{9} \left(9 \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^2 \, _2F_4\left(\frac{1}{12},\frac{7}{12};\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{2},\frac{2}{3},\frac{5}{6};\frac{1}{729}\right)+\Gamma \left(\frac{2}{3}\right) \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{6}\right) \, _2F_4\left(\frac{7}{12},\frac{13}{12};\frac{5}{6},\frac{7}{6},\frac{4}{3},\frac{3}{2};\frac{1}{729}\right)\right)$$
I try to reproduce the same sum but the term Gamma[1/2k+1/6] Could not express as product of Gamma function. Someone knows how Maple and Mathematica manage this issues?
Sum[((-4)^k*z^k*Gamma[k + 1/6]*Gamma[k/2 + 1/6])/(k!*Gamma[3*k + 1]), {k, 0, ∞}]


(1) For future use, please do not post only $\TeX$ equations, but also your Mathematica code. (2) I don't really understand your question. Can you please elaborate more clearly what the issue is? Mathematica gives you a result, so what is wrong with it?

I get the formula similar to the one shown. Maybe it's equivalent? https://i.sstatic.net/pzeqImfg.png

Maple and Mathematica give correct answers(equivalent almost the same),The series can be expressed by FoxH or MeijerG function:Sum[((-4)^k*z^k*Gamma[k + 1/6]*Gamma[k/2 + 1/6])/(k!*      Gamma[3*k + 1]), {k, 0, \[Infinity]}] ==   FoxH[{{{5/6, 1/2}, {5/6, 1}}, {}}, {{{0, 1}}, {{0, 3}}}, 4 z] == (  2 2^(1/6) \[Pi]^(3/2)    MeijerG[{{5/12, 11/12}, {}}, {{0, 1/2}, {0, 1/6, 1/3, 1/2, 2/3}},     z/54, 1/2])/Sqrt[3]

Thank you for your answers, maybe I don't express myself well, I wanted to know how you get the result maple or Mathematica directly, because you can't decompose the Gamma function [ak + b] if a is not an integer

$Version

(* "14.1.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 16, 2024)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

(sum1 = Inactive[
     Sum][((-4)^k*z^k*Gamma[k + 1/6]*Gamma[k/2 + 1/6])/(k!*
       Gamma[3*k + 1]), {k, 0, \[Infinity]}]);

Split the sum into even and odd terms
(sum2 = Inactive[
      Sum][((-4)^k*z^k*Gamma[k + 1/6]*Gamma[k/2 + 1/6])/(k!*
        Gamma[3*k + 1]), {k, 0, \[Infinity], 2}] +
    Inactive[
      Sum][((-4)^k*z^k*Gamma[k + 1/6]*Gamma[k/2 + 1/6])/(k!*
        Gamma[3*k + 1]), {k, 1, \[Infinity], 2}]) // TraditionalForm


Adjust the indices
(sum3 = Inactive[Sum][
     Simplify[((-4)^k*z^k*Gamma[k + 1/6]*Gamma[k/2 + 1/6])/(k!*
          Gamma[3*k + 1]) /. k -> 2 k], {k, 0, \[Infinity]}] +
    Inactive[Sum][
     Simplify[((-4)^k*z^k*Gamma[k + 1/6]*Gamma[k/2 + 1/6])/(k!*
          Gamma[3*k + 1]) /. k -> 2 k + 1], {k, 
      0, \[Infinity]}]) // TraditionalForm


Extracting from Entity["MathematicalFunction", "Gamma"]["Dataset"]
(repl = (Entity["MathematicalFunction", "Gamma"][
       "RelatedIdentities"][[19]] /. Equal -> Rule)) // TraditionalForm


(repl2 = Gamma[n_*k + a_] ->
    Assuming[Element[n, PositiveIntegers],
      repl[n, k, a] // Activate // Simplify][[-1]]) // TraditionalForm


(sum4 = sum3 /. repl2) // TraditionalForm


sum1 == sum4 // Activate // FullSimplify

(* True *)

EDIT: Generalizing and consolidating
gammaConvert[e_?(Head[#] === Inactive[Sum] &),
  int_Integer?Positive] := e /. Inactive[Sum][expr_, {k_, 0, Infinity}] :>
   ((Sum[Inactive[Sum][
        Simplify[expr /. k -> int*k + m], {k, 0, Infinity}], 
     {m, 0, int - 1}]) /.
     Gamma[(a_) + k*(n_)] -> (2*Pi)^(1/2 - n/2)*
       n^(a + k*n - 1/2)*Product[
        Gamma[(\[FormalK] + a)/n + k], {\[FormalK], 0, n - 1}])

(sum5 = gammaConvert[sum1, 2]) // TraditionalForm


The results are identical
sum4 === sum5

(* True *)


thank @Bob for your answers, brilliant idea but Mathematica can also handle Gamma[2/3 K+1/6] and in general the solution you gave is not valid in these cases how it to it??

When you have a different question, post a different question. Also, very few people will see a question in the comments of an accepted answer.

gammaConvert is Very usefool tool .If you add code from here https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/297146/transforming-expression-containing-powers-of-parameter   using for parameter k series looks better. +1)
